# Remove object key but keep its properties

Tags: javascript, object, methods, properties

Let's say there is an object that looks like this:

```
const before = {
  keyToBeRemoved: {    // <-- remove the key
    name1: "value 1",  // <-- keep the property
    name2: "value 2",  // <-- keep the property
    name3: "value 3",  // <-- keep the property
  },
  name4: "value 4",
  name5: "value 5",
  name6: "value 6",
};
```

I would like to remove the top level key but also want to keep all of its properties. The final result should look like this:

```
const after = {
  name1: "value 1",
  name2: "value 2",
  name3: "value 3",
  name4: "value 4",
  name5: "value 5",
  name6: "value 6",
};
```

Could you advise what is pattern to perform such manipulations with objects?

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

One (of many) possible solution is to use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax?retiredLocale=de).

First destruct the original object by "dividing" the object in the key to be removed and all the other properties. Then construct a new object using all the other properties and the properties of the key that was removed.

```js
const before = {
  keyToBeRemoved: {    // <-- remove the key
    name1: "value 1",  // <-- keep the property
    name2: "value 2",  // <-- keep the property
    name3: "value 3",  // <-- keep the property
  },
  name4: "value 4",
  name5: "value 5",
  name6: "value 6",
};
const { keyToBeRemoved, ...withoutKeyToBeRemoved  } = before; 
const after = { ...keyToBeRemoved, ...withoutKeyToBeRemoved }
console.log(after)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Can you extend it to remove 2 keys?

Comment: Certainly. E.g. if you also wanted to remove `name4` you could just adjust a single line: `const { keyToBeRemoved, name4, ...withoutKeyToBeRemoved  } = before;` and `name4` will also be removed. If `name4` was an object of its own you would have to adjust the following line as well to `const after = { ...keyToBeRemoved, ...name4, ...withoutKeyToBeRemoved }`.